# Question in Ahlfors

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)$ is analytic and $\Im(f(z)) \geq 0$ for $\Im(z) > 0$ show that $$\left|\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{f(z)-\overline{f(z_0)}}\right| 
\leq \left|\frac{z-z_0}{z-\overline{z_0}}\right|,$$ and $$\left|\frac{f'(z)}{\Im(z)}\right| \leq \frac{1}{y}.$$

In the section I am reading, the author derives a general form of the lemma of Schwarz and it strikes a close resemblance to this problem, however, I am not too sure how to approach this.

Any help or hints are appreciated!

Comment: See [Schwarz-Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz–Pick_theorem).

Comment: The first part is also answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/119863/42969.

Comment: @MartinR: Thank you for this! Also, I think that the second part falls immediately by letting $z_0 \rightarrow z$.