# Let $f$ be analytic and Im$f(z)>0$. Show $|\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{f(z)-\overline{f(z_0)}}|\leq|\frac{z-z_0}{z-\overline{z_0}}|$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, maximum-principle

Question: Let $f$ be analytic and Im$f(z)>0$.  Show $|\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{f(z)-\overline{f(z_0)}}|\leq|\frac{z-z_0}{z-\overline{z_0}}|$.

Thoughts: A nearly identical problem is asked here: [Why does $\frac{|f(z)-f(z_0)|}{|f(z)-\overline{f(z_0)}|}\leq\frac{|z-z_0|}{|z-\bar{z}_0|}$ when $\mathrm{Im}z>0\implies\mathrm{Im}f(z)\geq 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119863/why-does-fracfz-fz-0fz-overlinefz-0-leq-fracz-z-0z-b), but it is showing the other direction.  I felt like I could prove it in a similar fashion, but I don't have the "Im$(z)\geq 0$" assumption, just that Im$f(z)>0$, unless I am not seeing how that still holds then in this case.  I thought about maybe using some Schwarz here, but I thought there might be a way to salvage the proof from the attached problem.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: there is no entire nonconstant function with $\Im f >0$ so you need a restriction on the domain for the problem to have meaning

Comment: @Conrad ah, okay, so with that in mind, the problem is just like it is in the one attached then, correct?

Comment: Also, if you don't mind me asking, do you see any alternative arguments?   I don't think the one in the other question is difficult to follow, but I'm always intrigued to see any alternative approach or ideas!

Comment: The basic reason is that holomorphic functions from simply connected domains (eg half plane here) to themselves are contracting in the natural hyperbolic metric and for the upper half plane the expressions above give that more or less

Comment: @Conrad if you'd like to move your comment to an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.